# CodeIgniter Display data from database to view

Tags: codeigniter, view, model

I am trying to get all data from database and pass to view
I create in model function for getting data, and it's look like that

```
   public function get_data_from_db(){
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And in view I create foreach loop which look like:

```
<h6>Mjesto Odredista: 
<?php if($posts): ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<div class="well">
<h5><?php echo $posts['mjestoOdredista'];?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
        <?php  else : ?>
 <?php endif;?>
</h6>
```

and I get data to my view but passed 10 time:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone explane where did I make mistake ?

Comment: What is in your `$this->db->get('posts');` And used `<?php echo $posts['mjestoOdredista'];?>` in for loop, have to use `$post` values

Comment: This data I try to display in my view
http://imgur.com/a/OtTBP

Comment: Please provide the query you are using & please check both `$posts & $post` on view page. Because `$posts` might be a complete response array & `$post` might contact data's for each set of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your h5 tag contains $posts, it should be $post.

```
<h6>Mjesto Odredista: 
<?php if($posts): ?>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
<div class="well">
<h5><?php echo $post['mjestoOdredista'];?>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
        <?php  else : ?>
 <?php endif;?>
</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you change your model code to this

```
public function get_data_from_db(){
    //less lines of code, and using result() makes your loop easier
    return $this->db->get('posts')->result();
}
```

Then your view will look like this

```
<h6>Mjesto Odredista: 
<?php if($posts){
    foreach ($posts as $post): ?>

        <div class="well">
             <!--$post is an object, so u use the arrow to display it, instead of the [] for arrays
             note that this only works if mjestoOdredista is a column name from your database, if not, use the column name to display the value -->
             <h5><?=$post->mjestoOdredista?></h5>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach;

}else { ?>

     //do something else

<?php } ?>
```

I hope this helps you out. Let me know if you find any difficulty, lets sort it out.

Comment: Yeah I did :) Thank you a lot :) 
Erro was  in foreach look,I and just delete it and now it's ok :)